# Entity Framework and inconsistent performance with processing the results of a query

Tags: entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, newrelic

Just setup New Relic on our site and we noticed some odd spikes in one of our webapi calls.

At this point I have the problem boiled down to a single EF query that I moved out to its own method so I could use New Relic to instrument it..

The only thing the method does is

```
//I changed this from ToListAsync to ToList to see if it would help
var result = Context.Data.Where(x=> x.id = id).ToList();
return result;
```

That's it..

Using New Relic and also logging out all the SQL queries I'm fairly positive the issue isn't with the query being slow. New Relic says the method is only spending an average of 339 ms running against the DB and I see similar numbers from the trace data coming from EF. But the methods average execution time is 16 seconds.

Normally this method executes in under 2 seconds but every so often EF just seems to go off into lala land and it takes 60 or 70 seconds to finish whatever it's doing. But I've never seen the DB query itself take longer then 500 ms. And the query is retrieving pretty much the exact same dataset every time it runs..

I noticed in the logs that the long wait time was always between executing the query and closing the connection.. Here's an example output from the logs

- Application: 2015-02-17T10:04:11  PID[3556] Information -- Completed in 6 ms with result: SqlDataReader Application:  Application:
- 2015-02-17T10:04:11  PID[3556] Information  Application:  Application:
- 2015-02-17T10:04:22  PID[3556] Information Closed connection at 2/17/2015 10:04:22 AM +00:00

Notice the completion time is 6 ms but then there's a 11 second lag before getting to close connection

- I've tried removing async for this call but it doesn't help
- I tried using ConfigureAwait(false) on everything to see if it's some issue with trying to return to the original context
- I've tried manually managing the connection myself.. So opening at the very beginning then closing at the very end

This can't be from load because right now there's literally 2 users beta testing the Azure site... So the load is pretty much non existent.

I've tried to recreate this locally but haven't been able to... And I'm not really sure where to go from here debugging the issue besides slowly gutting the EF parts for something simpler like Dapper to see if that behaves more consistently.

Technology Stack:

- Sql Azure
- Azure websites scaled up to two instances
- EF 6 Async features
- web api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Sql Azure are you using?

We had a similar problem with Sql Azure Web (the one that will be retired soon)

We had a query using Entity Framework 6, agsint a table with about 700,000 rows. On my local sql server it took a second - on Sql Azure it took over 1 min!, worse still sometimes it even timed out

My guess is that Sql azure web is a shared sql server and that resources are limited.

Comment: We're on the S0 tier ... I moved it up to the S1 tier today to see if that would help but it hasn't really.. I'm thinking it has something to do with the spatial data that's in that table. We're working to optimize and cache what we can for now to see if that helps...

Comment: From what I have read (https://cbailiss.wordpress.com/2014/09/16/performance-in-new-azure-sql-database-performance-tiers/) S0 and possibly S1 seem to slow for for most apps - but it depends on the nature of the app.

Comment: Ok so what you're saying is that an avg_cpu_percent at 100 percent for an entire hour is a bad thing? :-)  super useful link there and I think that's it... At S0/S1 we're killing the CPU probably with our spatial queries...  Cool now I have some good tools  to actively monitor this and log some good usage data out to see where our work load fits against our tier... We're also going to be caching all the things really soon here so hopefully that can move us back down to S1..