# Are intermittent long CLR waits to be expected when updating geography columns in SQL AZURE?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-sql-database, spatial

I have a table with 14 records and the following query running through Entity Framework using "ExecuteSqlCommandAsync"

```
 UPDATE [par].[UserActivity]
                        SET Position = {0}
                        WHERE UserId=@userId
```

This query typically executes in about 2 to 10  ms.. But once or twice an hour it takes anywhere from 10 to 30 seconds.. Position is of type "geography"

I was able to capture some wait_type data during a few hiccups and noticed the waits are usually CLR_CRST or SQLCLR_APPDOMAIN with a few SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD's trickled here and there..

This server has pretty much zero load and this is just me testing with a single user. I'm fairly new with spatial data so maybe this is just something that comes with using a CLR type like this?

Comment: Seems odd.  I'm not used to working with AZURE but I've never experienced this with GEOGRAPHY or GEOMETRY types in SQL 2008, 2012 or 2014 using EntityFramework, ADO or plain SQL queries.  My assumption would be that something is temporarily locking down the table or the row.  As for what it is, I cannot help.

Comment: That was my thought but there are no other queries even running... I'm polling dm_exec_requests to get information about the wait stats and it's the only query executing and it's just sitting there forever on these waits... And currently when I select data from a different table with geographies it'll get hung up on  PREEMPTIVE_OS_CREATEFILE and just spin for up to 2 minutes... The only querying executing and it's just spinning for 2 to 5 minutes...

Comment: How odd.  I do remember reading somewhere in the past that Azure isn't as good with SpatialTypes as a dedicated SQL installation but that doesn't feel like it - I'm sure it was more on the Spatial methods than just insert / update functions.  Have you tried moving to the non Async EF method (just to check its not an EF / AZURE) issue?

Comment: yea I'd love for that to be the answer so I can just throw up my hands and move on :-)  I changed over a few methods to not use async but that didn't help. Changing out the whole stack to not be async would be a pain. Right now we're moving this whole process over to a Queue/Worker Role scenario with some Redis in the mix to streamline everything and hoping that resolves what's going on :-/

Comment: Alright so my theory right now is that we're actually hitting our scaling limit in azure... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593978/entity-framework-and-inconsistent-performance-with-processing-the-results-of-a-q/28714354#comment45746623_28714354... I've setup tasks to log all the resource utilization's and scaled the DB way up to see if we have the same issues the rest of the week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears the spatial queries we had were pushing the boundaries of what S1/S0 Azure can provide...  We'd gone from S0 to S1 and saw no improvements but I guess that was too soon to stop ramping up..

I eventually discovered this
sys.resource_stats

And saw that the cpu was peaking at 100 and then everything would just explode... Now that we're at S2 everything is staying happier and I'm just logging lots of resource data to keep track of the usages....